# Resizing a picture on a jsp page that's stored in a database

Tags: java, database, jsp, blob

I'm trying to set the size of a picture on a jsp page that i pull from a database.

I can get the image ok but it's filling the whole page.

Anyone know how to set the size of the picture

Thanks

Here's the code i have on my jsp:

```
<%

Blob image = null;  
byte[] imgData = null;  
Connection con;
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/comshopDatabase";
String uName="root";
String pwd="";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,uName,pwd);
    String sql="Select image from images WHERE id = '1' ";
    PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);

    ResultSet resultset=stmt.executeQuery();
while(resultset.next())
{

    Blob bl = resultset.getBlob("image");
    byte[] pict = bl.getBytes(1,(int)bl.length());
    response.setContentType("image/jpg");
    OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();



%>
<TABLE BORDER="1">
<TR>
<TH>picture</TH>
</TR>
<TR>


<td>Image</td><td><%o.write(pict);%></td>
    <%o.flush();
    o.close();%>

<TD> <%= resultset.getString(2) %> </TD>
<TD><%= resultset.getString(3) %></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<BR>
<%
o.flush();
o.close();
}
%>
```

Comment: This is terrible practice. Use a `servlet`.

Comment: I have a servlet for upoloading, this code is just for testing the displaying

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [image scaling library](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library-3-1-released/), the jar can be downloaded from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.imgscalr/imgscalr-lib).

Below is a simple example:

```
int width =1200, height = 900;
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(<sourceFile>);// You can use InputStream as well here, in place of source file
BufferedImage thumbnail = Scalr.resize(image, Scalr.Method.SPEED, Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_WIDTH,
                                       width, height , Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);
ImageIO.write(thumbnail, "jpg", new File(<destination file>)); // You can use OutputStream as well in place of destination file
```

Comment: would i put this part of the code in the servlet BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(<sourceFile>); and then the rest in the jsp?

Comment: You should put this code where-ever you want to re-size your image. I would recommend you to put this code in some Utility class. From servlet pass `InputStream` to this utility method and get back the resized `OutputStream`